# fprintf prints to file a garbage value in the middle of the correct output

Tags: c, function, printf

the output to the file is different than to the console.
in the console, I got the wanted value:
*************** Line: 100   *!*****  ***************

*************** Line: 101   *!%%%**  ***************

*************** Line: 102   **%****  ***************

and in the file:

```
100 *!*****/
101 *!%%-1077887800*
102 **%-1077887800***
```

it appears to be a garbage value.

```c
int PrintToFile(FILE *F, char J[mem_Cell])
{
    char *Line;
    char *Line_Num;
    int Num_Length;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int Line_C=code_line;
    Line_Num = (char *)(malloc(sizeof(char)*NUMSIZE));

    Line = (char *)(malloc(sizeof(char)*(NUMSIZE+(mem_Cell/2)+1+1)));

    Line_Num =NumToString( &Line_C);
    Line_Num = String_Reverser(Line_Num, 0);

    Num_Length = strlen(Line_Num);
    for(;i<Num_Length; i++){
        Line[i]=Line_Num[i];
    }

    Line[i]='\t';
    i++;
    for (j=0; j < mem_Cell/2; j++)
    {
        Line[i]= J[j];
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n*************** Line: %s  ***************\n", Line);
    Line[i]='\0';
    fprintf(F, Line);
    fprintf(F, "\n");
    code_line++;
    return  True;
}
```

Comment: 1. The assignment`Line[i]='\0'` is misplaced. 2. The call `fprintf(F, Line)` is perilous, if `Line` might contain `%` signs.

Comment: yes it does, how do I fix it then, I need to place % in my file

Comment: Use "%%" (2 percent) to print out a single one. The formatting routine interpret '%%' as 'output %'.

Comment: @Frankie_C No!  He just needs to change `fprintf(F, Line)` to `fprintf(F, "%s", Line)`. (Or maybe `fputs(Line, F)`.)

Comment: But all in all you're doing gobs more work here than you need to.  I think your whole `PrintToFile` function boils down to `fprintf(F, "%d %.*s", code_line, mem_Cell/2, J)`.

Comment: @SteveSummit Steve I Haven't understand where he insert the '%' in the string and my suggestion was as to insert them using a formatting functions as `sprintf()`. And yes you're right that was another error.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thak you!
That solved my problem. (The: fprintf(F, "%s", Line))

Answer (score 1):

Thank you,
I got a solution to the problem from @SteveSummit:
changing the `fprintf(F, Line)` To `fprintf(F, "%s", Line)`.